# Assigning an array to another array in one line

Tags: arrays, vba, function

I'm new to VBA, and I can't seem to work out a very simple concept - assigning one array to another, both being of equal size and type. Like in this example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim arr1(2), arr2(2) As Double

    arr1(0) = 5
    arr1(1) = 10

    arr2 = arr1 'error here

    Debug.Print arr2(0)
    Debug.Print arr2(0)
End Sub
```

Running this returns an error

> "Can't assign to array"

Now, I know I can iterate through every element with a For loop, but in some advanced cases, it is impractical to use - for example, I have a slow-loading function that returns an array, and because of that, I'd like to run it only once, taking it's whole return value and assigning to some other array, like this:

```
arr1 = Very_Slow_Function_That_Returns_An_Array()
```

But obviously, this won't work either, and will produce the same error. So, what can be done? Can someone give some advice on how to assign a whole array to another array without having to iterate through every element?

Comment: You are defining `arr1` as a `Variant` and `arr2` as a `Double` - That's a problem.

Comment: This us is a _nearly-XY_ problem: you may want to inquire why ‘Very_Slow_Function_That_Returns_An_Array()’ is so slow it instead!

Answer (score 2):

You can assign an array to another in VBA like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim arr1 As Variant
Dim arr2 As Variant

arr1 = Array(5, 10)

'Assign array1 to array2
arr2 = arr1

Debug.Print arr1(0)
Debug.Print arr2(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: But then the data type of the arr2 is still a Variant. How do I convert it to Double without having to iterate through every element?

Answer (score 1):

These variations work:

```
Sub main()

    Dim arr1() As Double, arr2() As Double

    ReDim arr1(0 To 1)
    arr1(0) = 5
    arr1(1) = 10

    arr2 = arr1

End Sub
```

or

```
Sub main()

    Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant

    arr1 = Array(5, 10)

    arr2 = arr1

End Sub
```

Third variation which is closest to OP code:

```
Sub main()
    Dim arr1(0 To 1) As Double, arr2() As Double

    arr1(0) = 5
    arr1(1) = 10

    arr2 = arr1 'no error here now.

End Sub
```

Comment: But then the data type of the arr2 is still a Variant. How do I convert it to Double without having to iterate through every element?

Comment: The first block of code will work as double.  I'll update it.

Comment: Wow. It does actually work like that. But why does it work when written this way, as opposed to my original example?

Comment: I thought at first it could be because you declare `arr2` as a double while leaving `arr1` as a variant (you need to declare the data type of each variable), then thought it's because your array has three elements (0 to 2) and then discovered that your code will work if you declare both as doubles and leave the size of `arr2` empty.  I'll add as a third variation to my answer.

Comment: I tried it now, and discovered that declaring as this -> Dim arr1(2) As Double, arr2() As Double , also works. But why? Can you explain why is it needed to omit the size of the arr2 to make this work?

Comment: No idea at the moment.  Keep in mind that `arr(2)` creates an array with 3 elements (0,1,2) unless you have `Option Base 1` at the top of your module.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thank you very much for showing me this simple workaround. Much better and convenient that using Variants.